# save entire cmd screen to image

Tags: batch-file, screenshot

I just finished writing a program, ([download here if you're interested)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fro8o6v30nxkb4z/Sketch.exe)  Basically, it is like an etch-a-sketch.  here's a screenshot of version 1: [image: v1]
Version 2 is more like a pixelated painting program.  Here's a  screenshot:[image: supports colors] As you can see, v2 supports 16 different colors.

Anyway, I want the users to be able to "save" their creations.  I know that I can highlight everything, and copy it into a text file, but this does not get the colors, and there isn't a clean way to do this (that I know of).

Is there a command line tool that I can download to save screen output as an image?  Or am I screwed?

By the way, This is just a batch file, compiled with [This](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/) program.  It only works compiled, because the compiler features advanced commands, the kind that allow me to have multiple colors in one window.  You can check out the source code [here.](http://pastebin.com/JZnv675F)  All lines starting with `REM` are the "advanced commands".

:edit
I was originally just going to go with a method that saves all of the text, but when I add colors, it looks something like [this.](http://pastebin.com/cz0siK3J)  Here is what it should look like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this commandline tool (I made it in AutoIt):

[Capture.exe](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9yh04HYXto1aVNycEI4LUtnQ1U/edit?usp=sharing)

Use :

```
capture.exe outputFile.jpg (png,bmp)
```

It will capture the entire screen.

EDIT :

You can use [THIS](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9yh04HYXto1Mm5ucDMzSmJ5RHM/edit?usp=sharing) new one :

Use :

```
Capture.exe "Title_of_the_Windows"
```

So in your bat, give a title to your CMD windows, using :

```
Title capture
```

and then display your colored text, and just make a :

```
Capture.exe "Capture"
```

This will create `Output.jpg`.

Comment: I like it, but (as you said) it captures the entire screen.  Do you know if there is a way to just get the cmd window?

Comment: Vista and higher come with snipping tool. This all windows versions - Prt Scn Copies the whole screen to the clipboard as a graphic or the screen with the mouse if using multiple monitors. Use MS Paint to paste the image. This is also known as Snap Desktop.
Depending on Prt Scn key settings on the Misc tab of a Dos program's properties, a Dos program can still print to printer with Prt Scn key.
 
Alt + Prt Scn Copies the active window to the clipboard as a graphic. This is also known as Snap Windows.

Comment: Ctrl + Prt Scn Copies the entire virtual screen when using multiple monitors to the clipboard as a graphic. Unlike the other two Print Screens above this one doesn't appear to have a name, or if so, it is not listed in the Windows' header files. Ctrl + Alt + Number Pad Minus Key Copies the active window to the Remote Desktop clipboard as a graphic (same as Prt Scn locally) 
Ctrl + Alt + Number Pad Plus Key Copies the whole screen to the Remote Desktop clipboard as a graphic (same as Alt + Prt Scn locally)

Comment: I was aware of the prtsc button, but not of the others.  With the above images, I used prtsc and cropped it in mspaint.  I guess I am looking for a more automated way to complete the process.

Comment: Use VBS appactivate then send a printkey to cmd. Turn the borders off in Personalisation (colours - advanced) and also shrink the titlebar. OR Use Command.com for your batch and load ansi.sys (32 bit windows only) for colours. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101875/en-au. Else you need to write a program or find one.

Comment: Check my edit I wrote a new one who just capture a windows by its Title.

Comment: FWIW Alt+Printscreen captures only the active window.

Comment: Hmm.  When I do what you say, it just creates a blank file on my desktop labeled ~capture~.  So here's what I did.  In batch file, I ran ~title capure~.  Then I ran ~ capture.exe "capture" ~.  No work.  Btw mini-markup isn't working on phone, so code is surrounded by ~ ~

Comment: Very strange for me it work perfectly. What's your OS ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this without external tools ,but you'll need .net framework (installed on windows from vista and above by default) and [screenCapture.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/screenCapture.bat)

```
call screenCapture screen.png png n
```